# Value for mixture distributions crossing using 'mixdist' in R

Tags: r, mixture-model

I have a plot (below) generated using the package "mixdist" and would like to know the exact value at which the two distributions cross one another rather than just estimating from the plot. I haven't come across this in any of the output information. Can this be obtained through mixdist?

Thanks for any help

[image]

Comment: If you know from what distribution the functions come and their parameters (surely, this is the point of fitting to the data), you can find the intersect(s) [like so](http://zonalandeducation.com/mmts/intersections/intersectionOfTwoLines1/intersectionOfTwoLines1.html).

Answer (score 0):

use locator() function to click on the point in the graph, followed by 'esc' key to give the values